# Two Spark Clusters in a Single Yarn Cluster

Tags: deployment, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to define 2 Spark clusters within a single, big, Yarn cluster? Spark in Yarn mode I mean, of course I could deploy Spark in standalone mode.

Say I have the following machines:

- h1, h2, h3
- k4, k5, k6
- s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6
- t1, t2, t3

The number represents the rack. On h I have HDFS, on k I have Kafka, on s and t I'd like to install Spark. On all machines there is Yarn, so in particular the cluster has a notion of rack locality.

I'd like to have 2 isolated Spark clusters on s and t, such that if I submit a job on any of the t machines (in Yarn mode), no task is allocated on the s machines and viceversa.

Is this possible?
Thank you, E.

Comment: Do you mean that you want submit 2 jobs in parallel on yarn ? A cluster is group of machine.

Comment: No, I mean cluster as group of machines -- I have a big yarn cluster and I wish to create 2 isolated Spark within that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and to be honest, doesn't make sense either.

Yarn is a resource manager, s* and t* are it's resources.
As you can submit the spark job from either of the nodes, yarn doesn't distinguish between them, so will allocate the resource you ask of dynamically, if you set parameter.

Now, it makes no sense to split your resource because, if a job takes 2 hour to finish on 3 nodes, might take only 1 hour to finish on 6 nodes. And yarn has it's queues, which keeps track on incoming job request, so it can dynamically reduce/increase allocated memory to the running job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to explore more -- in your example, I'm fine if that job takes 2 hours, but I want other higher priority jobs to not get delayed because of this first one being spawn on machines where it shouldn't. This is at least what I want to achieve, still unsure it's doable.

Comment: It is doable. Yarn can have multiple queues, with different priority levels. So if yarn is running a job submitted on lower priority queue, and a new job comes up on higher priority queue. Current running jobs resource will be reduced after current cycle finishes (if it has been submitted with dynamic memory allocation), and yarn will run higher priority job in parallel.